# Extending ZfcUser's UserController in custom module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

In my custom Module I have a custom `UserController` that extends the `ZfcUser` vendor's `UserController` in order to customize the `indexAction` and `registerAction`.

```
namesapce MyModule;

class UserController extends ZfcUser\Controller\UserController
{
    public function indexAction() { /* my code */ }

    public function registerAction() { /* my code */ }
}
```

I add the following in my custom Module's  `module.config.php`:

```
// some more config 

'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyModule\Controller\User' => 'MyModule\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        /**
         *  Overriding zfcuser route
         *  https://juriansluiman.nl/article/117/use-3rd-party-modules-in-zend-framework-2
         */
        'zfcuser' => array(
            'options' => array(
                // to override the slug
                // 'route' => '/profile',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'register' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\User',
                            'action'     => 'register',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

This gives me

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for ZfcUser\Controller\UserController::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-module\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 207 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-module\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Controller\UserController.php on line 66

And

> InvalidArgumentException
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\my-module\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Controller\UserController.php:69
>       Message: You must supply a callable redirectCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The zfc `UserController` has a redirect callback dependency in the constructor](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/src/ZfcUser/Controller/UserController.php#L66). This needs to be injected.

To register your custom controller you will have to make a custom factory and inject this dependency:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'MyModule\Controller\User' => function($controllerManager) {
            /* @var ControllerManager $controllerManager*/
            $serviceManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();
            /* @var RedirectCallback $redirectCallback */
            $redirectCallback = $serviceManager->get('zfcuser_redirect_callback');
            /* @var UserController $controller */
            $controller = new UserController($redirectCallback);
            return $controller;
        },
    )
)
```

You could also keep the old route definition and by using the same controller name by only overwriting the original `zfcuser` factory [from the ZfcUser `module.php` controller config](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/Module.php#L56):

You just have to load your module after the ZfcUser module and add this code in your `module.php`:

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'zfcuser' => function($controllerManager) {
                    /* @var ControllerManager $controllerManager*/
                    $serviceManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();
                    /* @var RedirectCallback $redirectCallback */
                    $redirectCallback = $serviceManager->get('zfcuser_redirect_callback');
                    /* @var \MyModule\Controller\UserController $controller */
                    $controller = new \MyModule\Controller\UserController ($redirectCallback);
                    return $controller;
                },
        ),
    );
}
```